# Formalizing sentences in predicate logic

Tags: logic

I would like to formalize "The lecturer is happy, if all his students love logic" using

- Lecturer as a constant;
- $H(X) = X$ is happy;
- $S(X) = X$ is a student;
- $L(X) = X$ loves logic;
- $T(X,Y) = X$ lectures Y.

Is $\forall X \ \ (S(X) \wedge L(X) \wedge T(\text{lecturer},X) \to (\text{lecturer}, X)$ the way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Replace (lecturer,$X$) with $H$(lecturer), at the end of the implication.

Comment: @frabala you're wrong. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure you can formalize that using Thank you..

Comment: Sorry, was this question just replaced? The answers are for the previous question!

Comment: @logiclover DON'T change the question text in order to make another question! Please, write the original question back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solutions is almost correct. The correct solution is:

$(\forall X \ \ (S(X) \wedge T(\text{lecturer},X) \to L(X) )) \to H(\text{lecturer})$

@frabala suggests you to replace $(\text{lecturer},X)$ with $H(\text{lecturer})$, at the end of the implication. While this is obviously necessary, because $(\text{lecturer},X)$ is a couple, not a term, this is not sufficient.

In fact, the resulting formula would be

$(\forall X \ \ (S(X) \wedge L(X) \wedge T(\text{lecturer},X))) \to H(\text{lecturer})$

but, in natural language, this means

"If it's true that every $X$ is a student, loves logic and "lecturer" lectures X, then "lecturer" is happy". 
But this is not the sentence you want! In fact, if "lecturer" is not a student, then exists an $X$ (i.e. "lecturer") for which it is not true that $S(X)$! Therefore, the premise of the implication is not true, and then you can't conclude $H(\text{lecturer})$, i.e. that the "lecturer" is happy! And this holds also if every students loves logic! And you didn't want to say that ;)

Update: Note that it is not necessary to use the constant "lecturer" to see that @frabala's solution is wrong. In fact, nothing assures us that every X is a student or "lecturer". X is just an element of the universe of the structure you are considering (and you don't know which it is). If the structure is "People all over the world", then choose X="Miley Cyrus". Then you obviously have the same problem, since Miley Cyrus clearly isn't a Math student, and even more clearly she doesn't love logic.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue. Since you plug "lecturer" to $H$, then $lecturer$ is in the domain. As a result, if the statement is true and all of his students love logic, then in order for the lecturer to be happy he must be a student himself, and furthermore a student of himself!

Comment: But we all are students of ourselves. We learn from $our$ mistakes...

Comment: But really, I think predicates apply on terms in general, and terms can be constants, too.

Comment: @frabala we *do* learn from our mistakes, but that makes us students of our mistakes, not students of our self's.